# Spinner won't appear in center (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

In my design portion of my code, I have my spinner in the center or the app, but when I run the application, it appears all the way up top. I looked up ways how to fix this and nothing is working. Can anyone suggest anything?

Here's my XML: https://gist.github.com/liliycode/43e45cd39c765716aebbdea4a4c08b89

And if needed, here is my java:

https://gist.github.com/liliycode/50246841d81a65ec177283ec0a488b52

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at the documentation for questions like this.

As recommended in the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html), I usually use `Relative Layout`.

The `centerInParent`, `centerHorizontal` and `centerVertical` work perfectly for these cases.

Example, using them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="American Writers"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/author_names"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    </Spinner>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: @Sam you should mark this as the answer if it resolved your issues